# Why is the audio I recorded infinite in length (js) ? 435:13:24

Tags: javascript, angular

Look at this,

[image: my audio]

I have used the following package
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-audio-recorder

And the following code is also following the example in the documentation

```
  stopRecording() {
    this.recorderState = RecorderState.STOPPING;
    this.cdRef.detectChanges();
    this.audioRecorderService
      .stopRecording(OutputFormat.WEBM_BLOB)
      .then((outputBlob: Blob) => {
        if (outputBlob) {
          this.currentBlob = outputBlob;
          this.currentBlobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(outputBlob);
          this.recorderState = this.audioRecorderService.getRecorderState();
          this.cdRef.detectChanges();
        }
      })
      .catch(errrorCase => {
        console.log(errrorCase);
      });
  }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

When you record audio using js, it is recorded as a stream of data. In my experience, all the streams behave like this in most of the audio/video players and only some of them were able to figure out the actual length. I suppose it is because the streams lack the metadata that gives the right information about these. Some players that managed to get the right information were professional editing tools, and I assume they somehow estimated the length with some other way. I really don't have any documentation that supports this reasoning but this is my best guess.

Edit:
Turns out my assumptions were right and you can fix this by using [this](https://github.com/yusitnikov/fix-webm-duration) library I found on Github. Credits to [daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6398044/daniel)